# File is corrupted after creating excel (.xlsx) file by using Apache POI with Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have created a Workbook/Excel in .xlsx format with Java using Apache POI API successfully. My code is as below that is created a file named "RiponAlWasim.xlsx" in D drive:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\RiponAlWasim.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
wb.close();
```

When I tried to open "RiponAlWasim.xlsx" it was shown the file is corrupted. What's the wrong?

Comment: Try `fileOut.flush()` before `close()`. Also, you might need to add at least one worksheet to the workbook, And you should close the workbook before writing

Comment: If I close the workbook before writing how will be written on it? There might be thrown "NullPointerException".

Comment: Thanks <Lance Java>. Yes, the main thing is - it needs to be created at least one worksheet to the workbook. After creating a worksheet it is working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It needs to be added at least one sheet to the workbook. So, after creating a worksheet the following code is working well:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Ripon");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\RiponAlWasim.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
wb.close();
```

Comment: Adding the line Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Ripon"); has solved the problem I faced.

Comment: we have flush the fileOut first then we can close the stream

Comment: Saved me hours of headache, I totally forgot to close the stream; closing the Workbook is not enough!

Answer (score 0):

Reason for corrupted excel: Improper closing of excel due to error inside loop statement

use try-catch block inside loop such that in catch block

- close the workbook variable
- close the fileoutput stream variable
- close the fileinput stream variable

After loop

- write on workbook using close the fileoutput stream variable
- close the workbook variable
- close the fileoutput stream variable
- close the fileinput stream variable

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in my case I found out that I had used write twice. So if you are getting such error one reason could be that there are multiple writes with same stream.

Answer (score -1):

I added the latest version of xalan (xalan 2.7.1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).